# A way to return unsubscribe from ThunkAction?

Tags: typescript, redux

Is there a way to return reference for unsubscribeSnapshot from ThunkAction like this:

```
export const someFetchAction = () => async (dispatch: Dispatch, getState: GetState) => {
  let unsubscribeAuth: UnsubscribeAuth | null = null;
  let unsubscribeSnapshot: UnsubscribeSnapshot | null = null;

  try {
    // Subscribe to auth state changes
    unsubscribeAuth = getAuth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      // check if authenticated
    });

    // Subscribe to snapshot updates
    unsubscribeSnapshot = onSnapshot(queryRef, (docsSnapshot) => {
      // dispatches payload data and sets loaded to true
    })

    return {
      unsubscribe: () => {
        if (unsubscribeAuth && unsubscribeSnapshot) {
          unsubscribeAuth();
          unsubscribeSnapshot();
        }
      }
    }

  catch(error) {
    // dispatches error and sets flag error to true
    if (unsubscribeAuth && unsubscribeSnapshot) {
      unsubscribeAuth();
      unsubscribeSnapshot();
    }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to call it from React's `useEffect`

```
const { loaded } = useSelector(state => ({
  loaded: state.fireReducer.loaded,
}))

const { someFetchAction } = useActions({
  someFireAction: fireActions.someFireAction,
});

useEffect(() => {
  let actionRef;
  if (!loaded) {
    actionRef = someFireAction();
  }

  return () => {
    actionRef.unsubscribe();
  }
}, [loaded])
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really seem to be needing to "unsubscribe" ***the thunk***, but rather the "thing" in the thunk needs to unsubscribe, the firebase subscriptions. In my opinion a custom React hook would be a better choice for this since you can couple it to the React component lifecycle, e.g. what you are using the `useEffect` hook for.

Example:

```js
import store from '../path/to/store';

const useFirebase = (loaded: boolean) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    let unsubscribeAuth: UnsubscribeAuth | null = null;
    let unsubscribeSnapshot: UnsubscribeSnapshot | null = null;

    if (!loaded) {
      // Subscribe to auth state changes
      unsubscribeAuth = getAuth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
        // check if authenticated
      });

      // Subscribe to snapshot updates
      unsubscribeSnapshot = onSnapshot(queryRef, (docsSnapshot) => {
        // store.dispatch payload
      });
    }

    return () => {
      if (unsubscribeAuth && unsubscribeSnapshot) {
        unsubscribeAuth();
        unsubscribeSnapshot();
      }
    }
  }, [loaded]);
};
```

Usage:

```js
useFirebase(loaded);
```

Comment: loaded is a property of the redux state and it is dispatched along with the payload if the thunk action were to succeed. I'm looking for a way to unsubscribe from onSnapshot() in case if the component calls componentWillMount.

Comment: @Katherine The `store` was imported and is available in scope in the custom hook, it can be used to access any current state via `store.getState()` and dispatch any action via `store.dispatch`. Is this insufficient for your needs?